# Swift - copy only non-nil properties from one Struct to another

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am trying to copy the values JSON decoded Firebase RemoteConfig's new values struct to another local instance same type. Obviously it replaces all old values from new object, but I want to replace only properties that have non-nil, so the local property will preserve their default values.

eg:

```
struct Config {
    let port: Int
    let details: String?
}

var localConfig = Config(port: 80, details: "Default configuration")
var remoteConfig = Config(port: 100, details: nil)

/// Here I want to copy only those properties are not nil
/// otherwise leave its default value
localConfig = remoteConfig

print (localConfig)
print (remoteConfig)
```

Obviously I can check each property for nil and assign individually but its not easy if the structure if huge and complex. I just wanted to know if there any standard option in Swift to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
struct Config {
var port: Int
var details: String?

 mutating func patch(with remote: Config){
    self.port = remote.port
    self.details = remote.details ?? self.details
 }
}
```

Usage:

```
var local = Config(port: 2, details: "myDetail")
var remote = Config(port: 3, details: nil)

local.patch(with: remote)
```

Comment: thanks. actually I have done a similar code currently. but the problem is when the strut gets bigger and complex its difficult and error prone to have conditions for each property. Especially the remote JSON here is given from Firebase RemoteConfig so I was wondering if there might be a robust way to do so in standard libraries. Appreciate your time burnsi